# Where must a .class file be located in order to be found by Tomcat 6 launched from Intellij Idea as exploded WAR?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, war

I need to debug a web application under Tomcat 6 and Intellij Idea 12.1.4 Ultimate.

When I try to deploy my web app as an exploded WAR file, I get following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ru/mycompany/MyClass
```

I looked into the directory with the exploded WAR (*File -> Project structure -> Artifacts -> MyApp exploded -> Output directory* equal to *C:\dev\myapp\exploded*) and found *MyClass.class* file in the *C:\dev\myapp\exploded\ru\mycompany* directory.

Since I'm getting the aforementioned error, this location is wrong.

Where should the *MyClass.class* be located inside the exploded WAR directory in order for Tomcat 6 to find it?

Comment: You can usually find class files within a WAR file in: /WEB-INF/classes

Comment: @hagbard I modified my project so that the class files are put into *WEB-INF/classes* directory, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ Idea automatically puts the element at the correct position in the tree, if you double click it in the *Available Elements* pane in the *Project structure* dialog.